# PHP + mySQL recursive select to create hierarchy menu

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, bootstrapping

I am learning PHP and mySQL, and need some help to create some code to build a hierarchy menu base on parent child elements. deep level will be 1 child.

This is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `businessprocess` (`bp_id` int(11), `bp_order` int(11), `bp_name` varchar(50), `bp_parent` int(11), `bp_active` tinyint(1), `dp_id` int(11)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

This the data:

```
INSERT INTO `businessprocess` (`bp_id`, `bp_order`, `bp_name`, `bp_parent`, `bp_active`, `dp_id`) VALUES
(1, 1000, 'Solicitud de Servicios (fijo y movil)', NULL, 1, 1),
(2, 1100, 'Personas', 1, 1, 1),
(3, 1200, 'Empresas', 1, 1, 1),
(4, 2000, 'Baja de Servicio', NULL, 1, 1),
(5, 2100, 'Personas', 4, 1, 1),
(6, 2200, 'Empresas', 4, 1, 1),
(7, 2300, 'Defunción', 4, 1, 1),
(8, 2400, 'Tercero', 4, 1, 1),
(9, 3000, 'Modificacion de Servicio', NULL, 1, 1),
(10, 4000, 'Recambio de Equipo', NULL, 1, 1),
(11, 3100, 'Personas o Empresas', 9, 1, 1),
(12, 3200, 'Tercero', 9, 1, 1),
(13, 4100, 'Personas o Empresas', 10, 1, 1),
(14, 4200, 'Tercero', 10, 1, 1);
```

This is the output needed for menu in PHP:

```
    Solicitud de Servicios (fijo y movil)
    --Personas
    --Empresas
    Baja de Servicio
    --Personas
    --Empresas
    --Defunción
    --Tercero
    Modificacion de Servicio
    --Personas o Empresas
    --Tercero
    Recambio de Equipo
    --Personas o Empresas
    --Tercero
```

any help is really appreciated. Thanks! AC

Comment: What you are needing can be done in so many ways. Why do you need a so-called 'recursive select'? You might consider using a multidimensional array to associate certain rows with their parent. Select bp_parent null first and then select bp_parent not null, then connect.

Answer (score 0):

First run

```
 SELECT bp_id, `bp_name` FROM `businessprocess` WHERE bp_parent IS NULL
```

Second for each of the returned result run

```
SELECT `bp_name` FROM `businessprocess` WHERE bp_parent IS NOT NULL  AND `bp_parent` = bp_id(gotten from the previous result)
```

It should display what you need